# Which model to buy in between TVS Apache RTR 160 4v Carb or FI?

Tags: carburetor, fuel-injection, apache-rtr

I am from Lucknow, India. I am planning to buy **TVS Apache RTR 160 4v** but I am really confused about whether to buy a carburetor version or fuel-injected version of the same.

The ex-showroom price of TVS Apache RTR 160 4v Dual disc ABS Carb is Rs.96,295 whereas the price of TVS Apache RTR 160 4v Dual disc ABS FI is Rs.1,02,545 means there is Rs. 6,250 difference between carb and FI.

**Website Reference -** https://www.tvsapache.com/rtr1604v.aspx

***Difference between carb vs fi is as follow:-***

**Maximum Power-**
Carb(12.14 kW @ 8000 rpm)/ FI(12.35 kW @ 8000 rpm)

**Power to Weight Ratio-**
Carb(0.0843 kW/kg)/ FI(0.0829 kW/kg)

**Battery-**
Carb(12V, 9Ah/6 Ah)/ FI(12V, 9 Ah/ 8 Ah)

**Headlamp-**
Carb(AHO 12V, 35/35W HS1 bulb, with all-time ON LED position lamp)/ FI(AHO 12V, 60/55W H4 bulb, with all-time ON LED position lamp)

**Kerb Weight (with 90% fuel & tool kit)-**
Carb(147kg)/ FI(149kg)

**0-100 kmph (sec)-**
Carb(15.36 Sec)/ FI(16.6 Sec)

**Mileage-**
Carb(40-50Kmpl)/ FI(45-55Kmpl)

**Features-**
Fi version has a gear positioning indicator and white backlight display whereas Carb has orange backlight display with no gear positioning indicator.

**My questions are:-**

Is it worth to buy Fi version and spend extra 6k more for Fi version for long terms basis?

Is carb machine more long-lasting and reliable than FI?

Is fi machine life is lower than as of Carb?

Thanks

Comment: You spend you money as you wish, we don't know all the criteria for your situation.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, thanks for the reply, I just wrote the difference in specifications but my main question is that is Fuel-injected engine less durable than Carb or not?

Comment: Welcome to the site @SaurabhLP. Your question is off topic because it's asking for shopping assistance and is not about maintenance or repair. Any answers you'd get are opinion based and therefore also off topic.

Comment: Hi @GdD, thanks for the reply, I like to say that the question I asked is less shopping assistance and more in technicality and mechanics.

Comment: On paper the injection model has more power and higher fuel consumption, but is a second slower to 100 kph – perhaps the gears are spaced differently. On the other hand, this is the production version of a racing bike. Do you want to be seen with the old technology (carburettors)? What is the bike *for*? If you buy one, when you have got over it, would another bike be more appropriate? Perhaps this page [Motorcycle Dilemma: Carbureted Vs. Fuel Injected](https://www.autoevolution.com/news/motorcycle-dilemma-carbureted-vs-fuel-injected-23635.html) can help you make up your mind over carb/fi.

Comment: Are you working on it? which is easier to look after with the tools you have?

Comment: Hi @WeatherVane, nice explanation on page. I consider its points very well.

Comment: @SolarMike I am planning to buy one... just confused whether to buy FI variant or Carb, which is more reliable?

Comment: Reliable comes down to looking after it... preventative maintenance is so named for a reason...

Comment: @SolarMike By seeing at the specs, should I go for FI or Carb?

Comment: So re-read my last two comments... you should be able to work your own answer out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FI vs Carbeurated: Pros and Cons](http://knowhow.napaonline.com/carburetor-vs-fuel-injection-short-history-pros-cons/)

As SolarMike is trying to say in the comments, if you are doing your own maintenance work, rather than using a shop or mechanic, that will change the decision for you. This is one of the reasons that (even though this is partly a technical question) I still think it to be a bit off topic as it is worded now (maybe you want to simply the post to "is fuel injection less reliable than Carbeurated" or something like that). Either method is quite reliable, but it depends largely on the maintenance actions *you* take and *your* decisions.

My bike is FI and I have 15,000 miles on it with no problems at all. All I've done is the maintenance recommended by the manual, and I doubt it will be a problem any time soon. You have to remember that FI is actually pretty old technology. It is just now becoming more popular on bikes after almost 100 years of being in use generally.